# Noscript and latest TBB (v3.6.4) -- recommended modifications to default settings?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, javascript

I recall that previous versions of TBB came with Noscript, but with javascript enabled by default. Since then, it would appear that the settings for Noscript (TBB v3.6.4) have been modified and javascript is now disabled, as tested with http://www.isjavascriptenabled.com; https://panopticlick.eff.org

I am curious, however, about the security of the current default configuration and what vulnerabilities the browser might plausibly be susceptible to. Are there any other adjustments to Noscript settings that might be beneficial without significantly affecting browser functioning?

(I am working  on the premise that the default Noscript configuration that the browser ships with may not necessarily be the most optimal, as was the case with previous releases of TBB.)

Answer (score 1):

- Click the NoScript button -> Select forbid all scripts globally
- Type "about:config" (without quotes) on your browser and press enter. Dismiss the warning. Find the javascript:enabled value and change it to false.

Comment: With regards to the about:config settings -- if a particular JS is disabled by the browser, will Noscript _always_ allow me to temporarily override this i.e. does Noscript offer control over all disabled scripts, or simply a subset of them?

Comment: @simulacrum I am not sure, but I believe about:config settings come first -so NoScript shouldnt be able to allow a script disabled by the browser.

Comment: No, I already tested it: even with javascript.enabled = false, it appears that Noscript can still override this (by allowing the different options in Appearance > Contextual Menu). I was curious, however, if maybe there are some things that this disables that Noscript cannot override.